# Need help installing; computer is now a paperweight

Tags: boot, system-installation

it's been a few years since running Linux and I wanted to get back into it. I used LiLu to put the most recent version of ubuntu on a USB stick and got rid of windows. Nothing but problems since. I've tried installing 6 times and have had a different result every time. First ubuntu didn't finish booting. Second it booted and installed okay but when I clicked restart it froze. Installed it again and it worked fine but when I rebooted it said there was no operating system installed. Tried installing again and it froze in the middle of the installation. I then clicked the "try ubuntu" option to install manually and it froze again. I'm in my sixth install now. It's almost done but I'm not optimistic. I'm guessing I'll get the "no operating system " error again. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Hmm... ok maybe ubuntu just tests you 5 times to make sure you're committed because so far the 6th install is working.

Comment: Information about the hardware you are using will be very helpful

Comment: possibly a hdd issue

Comment: Boot to the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and start the `Disks` app, select your disk in the left pane, then go to the "hamburger" icon and select `SMART Data & Tests`. Review the data. Run the tests. Then go to http://memtest86.org and download the free memory test and run at least one full pass to test your memory.